# Using a property from one property file into log4j2 properties file

Tags: log4j2

I have one properties file, let's say abc.properties and a log4j2.properties file. I am unable to access the logs.dir property which is present in abc.properties file into log4j2.properties file. This is done in order to switch the log file location based on different environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `abc.properties` and `log4j2.properties` configuration file are on the same directory then access `logs.dir` using below way in `log4j2.properties` file -

```
property.fileName=${bundle:abc:logs.dir}
```

---

Adding more details about environment as asked in comments -

**Project Structure -** A simple Maven project.

[image]

**Dependency -** I tried with version `log4j2 version 2.8.2` , below are dependencies in `pom.xml` -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Content of abc.properties -**

```
logs.dir = ./logs/abcfile.log
```

**Relevant content of log4j2 -**

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName=${bundle:abc:logs.dir}
appender.rolling.filePattern=${basePath}app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
```

As you can see in screenshot also, logs are getting generated on the path specified in `abc.properties` file.

Comment: I tried this one already but it's still unable to resolved the logs.dir property.

Comment: where these 2 properties files are placed ? Are these in same directory in classpath ?

Comment: which version of log4j2 you are using ? can you paste your dependency details ? FYI, I tried the same thing with log4j2 version 2.9.1 and it is working.

Comment: or it seems there is some other problem, is your configuration file working if you give some fix value for fileName ?

Comment: I am using log4j 2.8.2. I provided a fix value for filename and it works fine. Would you be able to share the screen shots of your test project? Thanks.

Comment: Added screenshot with additional details.

Comment: Thank you so much Vikas for your help. I accepted your answer.